# Rigorous synthetic geometry without Hilbert axiomatics

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, trigonometry

Are there books or article that develop (or sketch the main points) of Euclidean geometry without fudging the hard parts such as angle measure, but might at times use coordinates, calculus or other means so as to maintain rigor or avoid the detail involved in Hilbert-type axiomatizations?

I am aware of Hilbert's foundations and the book by Moise.   I was wondering if there is anything more modern that tries to stay (mostly) in the tradition of synthetic geometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might look at Hartshorne's
[*Geometry: Euclid and Beyond*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EJCSL9S6la0C&lpg=PP1&dq=hartshorne&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 2):

Try [*A Set of Postulates for Plane Geometry* by Birkhoff](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1968336?uid=3739864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21102247102467).

Answer (score 2):

There are some axioms systems such as Birkoff axioms which assume the existence of a field from the beginning.

For the synthetic approach the main axiom systems are those of Hilbert and Tarski.

You can also use Tarski's axiom as described in W. Schwabhäuser,
W Szmielew, A. Tarski, Metamathematische Methoden in der Geometrie.